# sql ignore Dependencies while creating database objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is their any way to ignore the dependencies while creating the database objects?
for example, i want to create a function on the database that uses the table(s), but i want this function to be created before creating the tables.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way around? Surely you need to know about the objects before you go to use them in the function, so why not make them first?

Comment: i want to make an automated system that can create db objects dynamically, and their are more tables that make use of functions.so i want to create functions before creating tables..

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any need for this. Do you see an advantage in doing this?

In oracle, you can create a function or package or procedure without the dependent objects present in the database but when you compile it says compiled with error and if you have to use them, then you have to re-compile the object again.

Comment: i want to make an automated system that can create db objects dynamically, and their are more tables that make use of functions.so i want to create functions before creating tables

Comment: Think from the database perspective. How will the database know that you are going to create tables which you have used in functions?